# Input from physical keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I have a fragment within a TabHost that has a single text input field.  I can enter text into this field with the soft keyboard fine, however, I cannot with the physical keyboard.  When the cursor is in the text field, I will hit any physical key, and the cursor will disappear so I cannot enter text. If I then hit the up key on the keyboard, the cursor will reappear in the text field and allow me to enter text.

Does anyone have any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Something is wrong with the focus (or touchmode)

Comment: @zapl Thanks, can you provide any additional details?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/touch-mode.html - or maybe you manually set focus to something else. It should usually work if you don't touch any focus related stuff in your app.

Comment: Did you ever figure this issue out? I am having the exact same problem right now.